# Adding a custom delete button to a custom list form in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-form

On a customized dispform.aspx page for document library, I'd like to add a delete button.  I'm trying this code from SharePoint Designer, but getting error in sharePoint designer 2007

**A string literal was not closed.**

```
<a href="javascript: if(DeleteItemConfirmation()) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete{',$KeyField,'=',$KeyValue,'};__commit;__redirect={mypage.aspx}))};" >
<img border="0" src="someimage.pgn" alt="delete" width="20" height="20"/>
</a>
```

Comment: can you write the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing quote for the "concat" (after the closing curly bracket of mypage.aspx) :

```
<a href="javascript: if(DeleteItemConfirmation()) {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;__delete{',$KeyField,'=',$KeyValue,'};__commit;__redirect={mypage.aspx}'))};" >
<img border="0" src="someimage.pgn" alt="delete" width="20" height="20"/>
</a>
```